# What is the different between adding generic type before initializing and ignoring it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I forgot to write `<Widget>` after `children:` in first code. but what is the difference between `children: <Widget>[]` and `children: []`.

```
 children: <Widget>[  
            Expanded(
            child: Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'), ),),], 

            children: <Widget>[    
            Expanded(
            child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),),];
```

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow Fawad. Please edit your question a bit so we can answer.

Comment: I find the answer not clear enough..  I mean, what's the problem you're facing that needs to be solved?

Comment: //////code1
children: <widget>[ Expanded( child: Container( child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'), ),),],
//////code2
children: <widget>[ Expanded(child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),),],

in first code,i have use container wrapped with Expanded and in second i have just use expanded class.but the result is same in both the cases.
what is the difference between both the code

Answer (score 0):

The  statement declares the type of what will coming next...if you don't declare the type the  will be selected for it. And it's suggested that you set the type to avoid further miss matching that may happen.

Answer (score 0):

> From [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html):
>
> Code that uses generics has many benefits over non-generic code:
>   Stronger type checks at compile time. A Java compiler applies strong
>   type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates
>   type safety. Fixing compile-time errors is easier than fixing runtime
>   errors, which can be difficult to find.

It is the same for language like Dart:

When you add `Widget` before initializing list, the expected type of the `children` parameter knows the types are matching if you add element that is type of `Widget` and if you add different type, you will get compile time message. If you don't add that generic type you only knows when runtime(Note that some basic types can be infered even without generic type but with custom type it will be difficult).

Widget `Column` `children` parameter expecting `List<Widget>`. So, it is like below:

```
List<Widget> chidren = <Widget>[];
```

And if did not add(default type if `dynamic` and Dart VM can infer the type at **runtime**):

```
List<Widget> chidren = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `List<Widget> chidren = <Widget>[];`two things are happening here:

1. A reference of `List<Widget> chidren` is created.
2. and an object `<Widget>[];` is assigned to that reference.

So,

By declaring the reference with `<Widget>` you are letting the compiler know that only the object that you want to accept for assignment to this reference should either be of type `Widget` or a sub-type of `Widget`.

And by assigning an object with `<Widget>` you are saying to the compiler that the current object is of type `<Widget>`. Here `<Widget>[];` you are saying that the list only contains `Widget` or sub-type of `Widget`.

if you don't specify the type before creating the List like `[];` then any type of objects are allowed to be in the list. But if you specify that the list is of type `Widget` then only `Widget` will be allowed in the list.

For testing this out try creating a `List list = [];` and try adding int or string or any arbitrary type of data in it. You will be allowed to save any kind of data in it. Now create `List<Widget> list = <Widget>[];` you will only be allowed to add widgets to the list and not any thing else.

What are generics good for ??

You will get an compile-time error instead of run-time error when you enter a wrong type of data into that object.

***Try on dart pad:***

`List<int> ints = ['string'];` // won't give you compile time error but a run-time error that string can't be assigned to int.

`List<int> ints = <int>['string'];` // will give you compile time error.

and when it comes to error, compile-time errors are far better than run-time errors.